# search csv file in a folder and insert in mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, parsing

I'm trying to parse files in directory/insert in mysql database based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889515/parse-files-in-directory-insert-in-database) and pretty much it is working except that csv values for each column are being rounded up and become INT values in database. I assume I need to change DECIMAL to something else, but I couldn't figure it out.

(Ex: 1.11 becomes 1, 45.5 becomes 46)

csv file:

```
test1,test2,test3,test4 
1.11,1.23,67.4,4.5
1.12,5.42,45.5,6.45
```

my code:

```
public void sqlTest()
    {
        string connectionString = "server=localhost;database=test;UserId=root;password=test;";
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"DROP TABLE test IF EXISTS";
                cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE test ( 
                                        Id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                                        test1 DECIMAL,
                                        test2 DECIMAL,
                                        test3 DECIMAL,
                                        test4 DECIMAL
                                    )";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            connection.Close();
            connection.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand insertCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                insertCommand.CommandText =
                    @"INSERT INTO test (test1, test2, test3, test4)
                      VALUES (@test1, @test2, @test3, @test4)";

                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@test1", DbType.Decimal));
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@test2", DbType.Decimal));
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@test3", DbType.Decimal));
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@test4", DbType.Decimal));

                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("D:/computer/csv files", "*.csv");

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
                    bool parse = false;

                    foreach (string tmpLine in lines)
                    {
                        string line = tmpLine.Trim();
                        if (!parse && line.StartsWith("test1"))
                        {
                            parse = true;
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (!parse || string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        foreach (MySqlParameter parameter in insertCommand.Parameters)
                        {
                            parameter.Value = null;
                        }

                        string[] values = line.Split(new[] { ',' });

                        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                        {
                            MySqlParameter param = insertCommand.Parameters[i];

                            decimal value;
                            param.Value = decimal.TryParse(values[i], out value) ? value : 0;

                        }
                        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }        
}
```

Any guidance or tips is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i were in your position, i would first change the table structure to this

```
 CREATE TABLE `test`(
   `test1` DOUBLE(13,2),
   `test2` DOUBLE(13,2),
   `test3` DOUBLE(13,2),
   `test4` DOUBLE(13,2) );
```

Then instead of reading the files' contents and doing an insert for each record, you can use **LOAD DATA INFILE** command to import csv file into your table in mysql.

Check this link [MySQL - LOAD DATA INFILE.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) for complete documentation.
Example usage is like this

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.csv' INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Depending on your server environment, you will need to edit the path of the csv file correctly and make sure your mysql local infile flag is set to 1 , if not you can set it using this command

```
mysql -u username -p --local-infile=1
```

So coming back to your code, it can be reduced to this

```
...
...
...

public void sqlTest()
{
    string connectionString = "server=localhost;database=test;UserId=root;password=test;";
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = @"DROP TABLE test IF EXISTS;
                        CREATE TABLE `test`(
                       `test1` DOUBLE(13,2),
                       `test2` DOUBLE(13,2),
                       `test3` DOUBLE(13,2),
                       `test4` DOUBLE(13,2) );";
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
        {               
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("D:/computer/csv files", "*.csv");

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
               query =@"LOAD DATA INFILE '"+file+"' INTO TABLE test
                        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                        IGNORE 1 LINES"; 
                using (MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
                {   
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }                   

            }
        }

    }
}
...
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! appreciate it